# Retrieve documents from a collection, which in turn have collections

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on react project, where i want to list the documents of the logged in user. The structure is such that documents I want to read has collections.

The database structure:
users(collection) -> user(document) -> repos(collection) -> **repo(document)** -> files(collection) -> files(document)

The repo(document) is the one I want to read. (It also has few other feilds).

This is the code that i tried:

```
const userRef = doc(db, "users", userId)
      const repoRef = collection(userRef, "repos")
    
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(repoRef);

      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
}
```

The error message:

> FirebaseError: Expected type 'DocumentReference', but it was: a custom CollectionReference object

Comment: Which line of code causes that error? Please edit the question to be clear.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Doug asked for, and please also respond using @.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to query only one document then you need to specify your repo doc ID:

```
import { doc, getDoc } from "firebase/firestore"

const docRef = doc(db, `users/${userId}/repos/${repoDocId}`);
const docSnapshot = await getDoc(docRef);

console.log("repo doc data:", docSnapshot.data())
```

If you want to query all repos then you need to query for collection:

```
import { collection, query, where, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";

const querySnapshot = await getDocs(
  query(collection(db, `users/${userId}/repos`))
)

querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data())
});
```

You can find more about it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data?hl=pt-br#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection)

Comment: By using the code snippet you provided, I was able to retrieve the fields associated with each document of the repos collection. But I also want to retrieve the docs of files collection, which are like children of the repos docs. Is it possible to do that in a single go like getting back a bigger json object? or should I query for the files I want after retrieving the repos docs?

Comment: This is not possible in a single query, if you need to get child collections data then you'll need to do a new query

Comment: If you'll need to do this in a single query maybe you should move files collection to files `map` variable inside the doc. This has some pros and cons. You could give it a try. Test it and see if this is better or worse in your case.